# Call DLL from Java using JNA

Tags: java, .net, dll, jna

I am new to accessing DLLs from Java using JNA. I need to access methods from a class within a DLL(written in .net). Form this sample DLL below, I am trying to get AuditID and Server ID. I am ending with the following error while I am running my code. Any guidance really appreciated.

/// Error ///

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function  'GetEnrollcontext': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

//DLL File Code//

```
SampleDLL.ProfileEnroll enrollcontext = new SampleDLL.ProfileEnroll();
enrollcontext.Url =” url”;
enrollcontext.AuditIdType = SampleDLL.ProfileId;
enrollcontext.AuditId = “22222222 “; 
enrollcontext.ServerId = “server1”;
```

/// Java Code ///

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import dllExtract.DLLExtractTest.SampleDLL.Enrollcontext;


public class SampleDLLExtract {

    public interface SampleDLL extends Library {
        SampleDLL INSTANCE = (SampleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("SampleDLL",
            SampleDLL.class);

        public static class Enrollcontext extends Structure { 

            public String auditId;
            public String serverId;
        }
            void GetEnrollcontext(Enrollcontext ec);                     // void ();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleDLL sdll = SampleDLL.INSTANCE;
        SampleDLL.Enrollcontext enrollContext = new SampleDLL.Enrollcontext();
        sdll.GetEnrollcontext(enrollContext);

        System.out.println(sdll.toString(sdll.GetEnrollcontext(enrollContext))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: After lot of research, it is confirmed that it is not possible to use JNA framework to call DLL files that coded in VB or C Sharp. JNA is working with System DLL but not good for third party DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

in fact there is a solution for you to use C#, VB.NET or F# code via JNA in Java (and nothing else)! and it is also very easy to use:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

with this package all you need to do is, add [RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport] to your methods like that:

C# .dll Project:

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static String yourFunction(String yourParameter)
{
    return "CSharp String";
}
```

Java Project:

```
public interface jna extends Library {
    jna INSTANCE = (jna) Native.loadLibrary("yourCSharpProject.dll", jna.class);
public String yourFunction(String yourParameter);
}
```

use it in the code:

```
System.out.println(jna.INSTANCE.yourFunction("nothingImportant"));
```

Viola!

As already mentioned it works very easy, but this solution has some limitations:

- only available for simple datatypes as parameter & return values
- no MethodOverloading available. yourFunction(String yourParameter) and yourFunction(String yourParameter, String yourSecondParameter) does not work! you have to name them differently
- Use arrays as parameter or return values. (JNA offers StringArray, but I am not able to use them in C#) (maybe there is a solution, but I couldn't come up with one so far!)
- if you export a method you can't call it internally in your C# code (simple to bypass that by the following:

.

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static Boolean externalAvailable(String yourParameter)
{
    return yourInternalFunction(yourParameter);
}
```

With C# it works great, with VB.NET and F# I have no experience.
hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I went through jn14net  (http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) documentation and would like to try a shot. Do you have any piece of advice?

Comment: advice for jni4net? not a general one, sorry.

the basic samples look nice, but idk how to use them with other classes then the c# classes, which are already included in the jni4net.version.jar